# Android: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.Build.SERIAL

Tags: android

In android, I have the following error thrown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.Build.SERIAL
```

It happens only on certain devices, for instance: "sec_smdk6410" or "sdkDemo".

I have tried to catch the exception but it ignores the try/catch block.

```
    try {
        return android.os.Build.SERIAL;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
```

Is there anyway I can detect if this error will be thrown in order to adapt my code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation states it is only available for API level 9.
You could check the API level by using:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
    // safe to use 
else
   // ignore
```

Untested, but I would give it a go

Comment: Just a heads up but this version check only works if you are running on a device **API > 4**. If the device is API level 4 or lower (donut or lower) then the app will crash with a [`VerifyError`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/VerifyError.html). The reason is because there was a change starting with Android 2.0 to the way the Dalvik VM loads classes until it actually uses them. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7265487/708906

Answer (score 0):

The [`NoSuchFieldError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchFieldError.html) is not an `Exception`, it's an `Error` (that's why it was not caught in your code).

Both `Errors` and `Exceptions` are `Throwables`. That means `Errors` can also be caught:

```
try {
    return android.os.Build.SERIAL;
} catch (NoSuchFieldError e) { // Notice the change here
    return null;
}
```

More on the ["Differences between Exception and Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-between-exception-and-error).